# Connecting together DIR-615 and DIR-655

Tags: firewall, routing, home-networking, dir-655

On my DIR-655 my internal network is: 192.168.0.x
On my DIR-615 my internal network is: 192.168.1.x
They are both connected to my firewall PIX 501 box
The PIX itself is connected to the comcast modem.

I briefly looked at the menu options on those router and they look similar, however I'm not sure what's the best way to connect those two together so that I can go between those networks. (printing, file browsing, etc.)
I'm not sure if I have to do this somehow on those two router or on the PIX itself, or probably on all of them.
If anyone has experience with something like that please let me know..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way would to turn one of those routers into a bridge so that everything is on the same network.

So take your DIR-655 for instance and turn that into a bridge and connect it to the DIR-615.  The DIR-655 would basically just act as an extension of the DIR-615 and connect whatever computers are connected to it to the DIR-615.

To this, you need to disconnect the DIR-655 from the modem and physically connect it to one of the DIR-615 ethernet ports.  Turn off DHCP on the DIR-655 and give it a manual IP address outside of the DIR-615's DHCP range.  So if the DIR-615 is assigning IPs 192.168.1.2-192.168.1.50 for computers connected to it for instance, give the DIR-655 a manual IP address of 192.168.1.51.

Now the computers connected to the DIR-655 will receive an IP address from the DIR-615, if they are set to automatic DHCP, and everything will be on the 192.168.1.x network.

Answer (score 0):

That's an odd mix of good hardware and crappy stuff

Turn off DHCP on both D-link routers, set them to let the firewall handle DHCP. connect both routers to the firewall